# How to silently install a certificate on Linux using .NET

Tags: .net, linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I have a .NET exe that when I run(on windows), asks to install a certificate into the trusted root. I assume that this will also be the case on Linux.
The problem is that there is a UI prompt dialog being displayed.

I need this to run on a Linux server automatically, silently install the cert without the UI prompt.

How can I do this with .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That prompt is a feature of the Windows OS, not of .NET.  It does not exist on Linux.